# R remove currency reference in numeric value

Tags: r, currency

How can I remove the currency references. I have some values with currencies sometime shown with 3 characters and sometimes with $. For example:

```
Val.curr <- c('GBP 550.00', 'EUR 716.50', 'EUR 842.00', '$ 1541.54',  '$ 1541.54')
```

I can remove the currencies like:

```
as.numeric(gsub("\\EUR", "", Val.curr[3]))
as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "", Val.curr[4]))
```

But, is there a more efficient way to remove them all at the same time?

Comment: `as.numeric(gsub('[GBP|EUR|$]', '', Val.curr))`

Comment: You could try `readr::parse_number()`

Comment: There are actually many more currencies

Comment: `sub(".*\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+)", "\\1", Val.curr)`

Comment: readr does the job. Thanks Chrisss

Comment: @Chrisss - post it as an answer so that the question is not listed as unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Chrisss comment above I've found the solutions, which I post here as it might help some one else:

```
install.packages("readr")
library(readr)
readr::parse_number(Val.curr)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub`

```
as.numeric(sub("[^0-9.]+", "", Val.curr))
#[1]  550.00  716.50  842.00 1541.54 1541.54
```